# i am trying to display data of authenticated user from my firebase database in textviews, i tried a lot of stuff but i does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is the autorized node in my database

```
cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2
         ID:"cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2"
         mail:"pakistan@gmail.com"
         mobile: "03000101010"
         name: "pakistan"
```

i want these 4 attribute's data to be displayed on textviews in an activity
I am saving data by another java class by this method

```
String id= firebaseAuth.getUid();
AppUser appUser = new AppUser(nameUser , usermobile , userEmail, id);
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(appUser);
```

Comment: What didn't work? What did you try and what error do you get?

Comment: the activity in which i try the code crashes,

Comment: Also i cannot find a reliable code to display the data from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your database look something like this:

```
 Firebase-root
     |
     ------- cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2
                    |
                    --- ID: "cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2"
                    |
                    --- mail: "pakistan@gmail.com"
                    |
                    --- mobile: "03000101010"
                    |
                    --- name: "pakistan"
```

To display the data in a `TextView`, please use the following code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String ID = dataSnapshot.child("ID").getValue(String.class);
        String mail = dataSnapshot.child("mail").getValue(String.class);
        String mobile = dataSnapshot.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        String text = ID + " / " + mail + " / " + mobile + " / " + name;
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The text that will be displayed in your TextView will be:

```
cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2 / pakistan@gmail.com / 03000101010 / pakistan
```

Comment: ` listView.setText(text);       name.setText(text);`  i am trying to set it to my text view its not setting it

Comment: What is ` name.setText(text)`? Should be: `listView.setText(text);`. Do you have an error?

Comment: name is the textview id that i am using in my activity

Comment: When you are setting the text to that TextView, what is happening? Do you have an error? If is an error, paste it here.

Comment: Error:(56, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)

Comment: This means that `name` isn ot a TextView. Can you share the code for that please?

Comment: ` private Button back;
    private TextView name;
   private FirebaseDatabase mref;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        back = findViewById(R.id.backTobutton);
        name= findViewById(R.id.databaseName);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
` i created and initialized the text view

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Please see my updated answer. Should be `TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
   textView.setText(text);` Does it work now?

Comment: Please use this line of code: `Log.d("TAG", ID + " / " + mail + " / " + mobile + " / " + name);` What does it print in the logcat?

Comment: it just printed       null/null/null/null/     in the text view 
logcat was showing nothing

Comment: I understand. This means that the reference is wrong. Please show me your entire database structure.

Comment: `myfirstapp-d1d59
cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2
ID: 
"cXTFh3uwRVhm4CaVvk4BRF1t4Ze2"
mail: 
"pakistan@gmail.com"
mobile: 
"03000101010"
name: 
"pakistan"
`
the root is ID that is generated by firebase itself

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I just have removed the `users` node. Does it work now?

Comment: yes it worked thanks alot
one more thing though , how do I get the ID in Integer form

Comment: My pleasure sir